# Typescript error when passing arguments to super class. `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter (TS2556).`

Tags: typescript, super, jsdoc, spread

The following gives error TS2556, how do I fix it?

```
class Test {
    constructor(x: number) {}
}

class Test2 extends Test {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args); // TS2556
    }
}
```

Or if you are using jsdoc with tsc for typechecking:

```js
class Test {
    /**
     * @param {number} x
     */
    constructor(x) {}
}

class Test2 extends Test {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `ConstructorParameters<T>`, if you are calling a function you can get away with just `Parameters<T>`.

```
class Test {
    constructor(x: number) {}
}

class Test2 extends Test {
    constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Test>) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

Or for jsdoc:

```js
class Test {
    /**
     * @param {number} x
     */
    constructor(x) {}
}

class Test2 extends Test {
    /**
     * @param  {ConstructorParameters<typeof Test>} args
     */
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```