# Use ConstructorParameters to create utility for various JavaScript API static methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, jsdoc

I'm reading [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183582/typescript-error-when-passing-arguments-to-super-class-a-spread-argument-must), trying to understand why I'm getting the same error even if I've done almost the same.

My original code.

```js
/**
 * Shortcut for `Array.from()` static method.
 * @param  {...any[]} args array-like value
 * @returns {Array}
 */
const ArrayFrom = (...args) => Array.from(...args);
//                                     >>ERROR here
export default ArrayFrom;
```

```js
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
```

Now after defining with `ConstructorParameters`

```js
/**
 * Shortcut for `Array.from()` static method.
 * @param  {ConstructorParameters<typeof Array>} args array-like value
 * @returns {Array}
 */
const ArrayFrom = (...args) => Array.from(...args);
//                                     >>SAME ERROR here
export default ArrayFrom;
```

I get the same error, at the same expression. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: You're collecting the arguments to your `ArrayFrom()` function into an **array** called args. You don't need to spread again; simply return `Array.from(args);`, or for that matter just return `args` by itself.

Comment: If you expect to pass (as your comment notes) an "array-like value", then you don't need the spread syntax at all, because `Array.from()` already understands array-like values.

Comment: Thank you. I already did that, but I was confused because `ArrayFrom = (...args) => Array.from(...args);` actually works in the browser console.